# CALayer animating the Bounds

Tags: iphone, core-animation

Is it possible to animate the bounds of the CALayer on iPhone? How to implement that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0f];
[[self view] setBounds:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 200.0f, 200.0f)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

This will animate a view controller's view from it's current bounds to a bounds of 200 x 200 over 1 second. It won't change the origin--just the size of the bounds rectangle. This is implicit animation by the way. If you want a more complicated animation, look at using CABasicAnimation and animating explicitly.

Comment: Thanks!
This is what I want to do:
Imagine imagesize is 300 x 300. I want the image size to remain the same, but animate the bound area to focus on 100 x 100 specific point of the image.

I googled and go through the document and kind of confusing about the frame and bounds.

Comment: If you want to change the position and the bounds you can either animate both using -setCenter: and -setBounds: respectively, or you can animate the frame with a call to -setFrame which will animate both. It's not clear what you are wanting though. If you have a layer that overlays an image, you can animate that layer to focus in as you're describing. In that case though, you'll need to make sure your focusing layer has -setMasksToBounds: set to YES.

Comment: @MattLong : can you help me with my question > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353284/animate-image-inside-a-smaller-frame-in-ios ? It's something similar to what sooon is looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to animate the visible part of an image inside a layer, were the layer itself maintains size and position?

That's what `CAScrollLayer` is made for. Use a `CAScrollLayer` in place of your current Layer and add image-rendering layerl as a subLayer to the `CAScrollLayer`. You can then use the `transform` property of the sublayer to achieve that effect.